# connecting a snow api & postgresql database using PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, scripting, servicenow

I have a postgresql database and servicenow change ticket list, which i need to connect & automate. The plan is to be able to automate, using python, to pull any new ticket updates in servicenow and have that update the status of whatever ticket in the postgresql database. I have some scripts written for the servicenow side, but am a little confused on how to kinda merge servicenow/postgresql to work together.

Here is some example code i'm working with from servicenow,

```
class tops_servicenow(object):
    def __init__(self, user_id, password_auth):
        self.s = requests.Session()
        self.s.verify = False
        self.s.auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(user_id, password_auth)
        self.client = pysnow.Client(host="snow.aepsc.com", session=self.s)
        # self.client = pysnow.Client(host="servicenow.aepsc.com", session=self.s)
        self.all_assets = []


    def assets_information(self, sys_id, dup_checking=False):
        # Retrieve specified sys_id
        asset_information = self.client.resource(api_path='/table/cmdb_ci')
        if isinstance(sys_id, list) is True:
            if dup_checking is True:
                asset_list = []
                dup_check = []
                for ids in sys_id:
                    if ids in dup_check:
                        break
                    else:
                        asset_list.append(asset_information.get(query={'sys_id': ids}).one())
                        dup_check.append(ids)
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @GordonMohrin moreover, i'm looking for a python script to iterate through servicenow change tickets and update with any changes that have been made in servicenow. i'm just not 100% sure on how to write that script. thanks!